# Read IP addresses and TTL from DNS response with dpkt

Tags: python, pcap, dpkt

I'm using dpkt for reading a pcap file.

```
        try: dns = dpkt.dns.DNS(udp.data)
        except: continue

        if dns.qr != dpkt.dns.DNS_R: continue
        if dns.opcode != dpkt.dns.DNS_QUERY: continue
        if dns.rcode != dpkt.dns.DNS_RCODE_NOERR: continue
        if len(dns.an) < 1: continue

        for answer in dns.an:
            if answer.type == 5:
                print "CNAME request", answer.name, "\tresponse", answer.cname
```

I'd like to read the ip address and the TTL for every answer. I did `dir(answer)` but I could not find anything that seems to return the ip addresses/TTL of the response, and I'm not finding anything in the documentation.

Is there a method for that?

Answer (score 2):

[From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337878/parsing-pcap-files-with-dpkt-python)

I assume you are reading the pcap file with something like this:

```
import dpkt
import sys

f=file(sys.argv[1],"rb")
pcap=dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)
```

Parse each layer individually starting with the Ethernet.

```
for ts, buf in pcap:
  eth=dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
  ip=eth.data
  udp=ip.data
```

Then pull the relevant TTL and IP values from the IP header.

TTL and IP values are in the IP header, not the DNS answer.

Comment: I don't think you will see DNS information in the IP header. the IP layer is below DNS

Comment: That is correct. But you can parse the IP header before processing the DNS data.

Answer (score 1):

The RR object has a `ttl` property which is what you are looking for:

```
try:
    dns = dpkt.dns.DNS(udp.data)
except:
    continue

    if dns.qr != dpkt.dns.DNS_R: continue
    if dns.opcode != dpkt.dns.DNS_QUERY: continue
    if dns.rcode != dpkt.dns.DNS_RCODE_NOERR: continue
    if len(dns.an) < 1: continue

    for answer in dns.an:
        if answer.type == 5:
            print "CNAME request", answer.name, "\tresponse", answer.cname, "\tttl", answer.ttl
```

Answer (score 1):

(This is a woefully late answer.)  Bob are you asking for the IP address of the server that sent the reply, or the IP address for the name within a CNAME record?  The canonical name (CNAME) data in a resource record (RR) portion of a DNS reply has only a domain name and a TTL. The name servers that I have tested against return an IP address for the CNAME answer in a different additional-info RR record.

If you want to read the original chapter and verse: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt

Here is a bit of Python code using dpkt that lets you generate and explore the contents of DNS replies.

```
import dpkt
import random
import socket

# build query
query_id = int(random.random() * 10000)
query = dpkt.dns.DNS(id=query_id)
my_q = dpkt.dns.DNS.Q(name="www.yahoo.com")
query.qd.append(my_q)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.connect(("8.8.8.8", 53))
sock.send(str(query))
buf = sock.recv(0xffff)

# parse response
response = dpkt.dns.DNS(buf)
if query_id != response.id:
    print "Expected %d but received id %d" % (query_id, response.id)
elif response.qr != dpkt.dns.DNS_R:
    print "Not a response!"
elif response.opcode != dpkt.dns.DNS_QUERY:
    print "Not a query op!"
elif response.rcode != dpkt.dns.DNS_RCODE_NOERR:
    print "Not a successful response!"
elif len(response.an) == 0:
    print"Response has no answers!"
else:
    print "%d bytes received, id is %d" % (len(buf), response.id)
    for rr in response.an:
        print "AN: class is %d, type is %d, name is %s" % (rr.cls, rr.type, rr.name)
        if hasattr(rr, 'ip'):
            print "\tIP is %s" % socket.inet_ntoa(rr.ip)
    for rr in response.ns:
        print "NS: class is %d, type is %d, name is %s" % (rr.cls, rr.type, rr.name)
    for rr in response.ar:
        print "AR: class is %d, type is %d, name is %s" % (rr.cls, rr.type, rr.name)
```

The results that I see (sitting on the East coast):

```
240 bytes received, id is 5848
AN: class is 1, type is 5, name is www.yahoo.com
AN: class is 1, type is 1, name is fd-fp3.wg1.b.yahoo.com
    IP is 98.139.180.149
AN: class is 1, type is 1, name is fd-fp3.wg1.b.yahoo.com
    IP is 98.139.183.24
NS: class is 1, type is 2, name is wg1.b.yahoo.com
NS: class is 1, type is 2, name is wg1.b.yahoo.com
NS: class is 1, type is 2, name is wg1.b.yahoo.com
NS: class is 1, type is 2, name is wg1.b.yahoo.com
AR: class is 1, type is 1, name is yf2.yahoo.com
AR: class is 1, type is 1, name is yf1.yahoo.com
AR: class is 1, type is 1, name is yf3.a1.b.yahoo.net
AR: class is 1, type is 1, name is yf4.a1.b.yahoo.net
```